# My busybox gets corrupted?

Tags: cyanogenmod, huawei-u8150, z4root, busybox

Recently I just downgraded my busybox to 1.18.2 version using the jRummy's BusyBox Installer. I was previously having busybox preinstalled by CM7.2 custom ROM.

Then I immediately tried to install the latest, 1.19.4 version using the same app..

It could have shown some error message, but I wasn't sure. Maybe the download didn't proceed fully. But now onwards, I am getting "No root" message when I try to launch the BusyBox Installer. I tried everything, forgetting the app from SuperUser (by chainsfire) app and reauthorizing root for it, clearing data, rebooting the phone etc.

Apps like link2sd also cannot get "root" privileges all of a sudden!!

Strange thing is, z4root app detects my phone as already rooted. And when I try to click "re-root", the process goes on and on and nothing happens.

Why has this happened? Is this because JRummy's busybox overwrites the CM7.2 build one? Should I never try updating busybox when I'm on CM7.2?  or is it because I have to specify correct path? /system/xbin in that busybox installer?

Now all I need is to make busybox and more importantly, get my root back to work properly hopefully without having to reinstall my ROM. Any ideas?

Huawei IDEOS u8150 running Cyanogenmod 7.2-RC1

Update : I tried rooting/unrooting etc using SuperOneClick v 2.3.3.0. It doesn't work either. Here's its log (apparently there are lots of "illegal instruction" errors where it shouldn't be):-

```
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.release > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=31336

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

2.3.7

END:31336export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=93231

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Huawei

END:93231export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=48975

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

U8150

END:48975export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=38960

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

eng.aorth.20120306.105455

END:38960export PS1=""



ls -l /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=96369

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:96369export PS1=""



ls -l /system/bin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=35669

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:35669export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=40902

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:40902export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=40829

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied

END:40829export PS1=""



busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=31488

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:31488export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=65795

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:65795export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/sh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=78056

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:78056export PS1=""



chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=86427

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:86427export PS1=""



cd /data/local/tmp/ > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=46214

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:46214export PS1=""





export TEMPRANDOM=23335;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;./zergRush

./zergRush: permission denied

END:23335export PS1=""

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.release > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=81716

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

2.3.7

END:81716export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=13472

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Huawei

END:13472export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=98688

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

U8150

END:98688export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=22140

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

eng.aorth.20120306.105455

END:22140export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=82615

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:82615export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=43597

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied

END:43597export PS1=""



busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=15262

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:15262export PS1=""



ls -l /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=64824

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:64824export PS1=""



ls -l /system/bin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=74020

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:74020export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=74614

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:74614export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/sh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=16835

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:16835export PS1=""



chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=27596

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:27596export PS1=""



cd /data/local/tmp/ > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=49127

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:49127export PS1=""





export TEMPRANDOM=29618;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;./zergRush

./zergRush: permission denied

END:29618export PS1=""

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=12726

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:12726export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=54207

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied

END:54207export PS1=""



busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=21168

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:21168export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=95174

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Huawei

END:95174export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=36720

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

U8150

END:36720export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=21915

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

eng.aorth.20120306.105455

END:21915export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.release > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=37315

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

2.3.7

END:37315export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=54134

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:54134export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/sh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=90391

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:90391export PS1=""



chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=35822

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:35822export PS1=""



cd /data/local/tmp/ > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=58244

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:58244export PS1=""





export TEMPRANDOM=61534;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;./zergRush

./zergRush: permission denied

END:61534export PS1=""

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=32756

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Huawei

END:32756export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=45540

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

U8150

END:45540export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=53091

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

eng.aorth.20120306.105455

END:53091export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/sqlite3 > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/sqlite3 >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=38213

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/sqlite3 >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:38213export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=66171

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:66171export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=57497

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied

END:57497export PS1=""



busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=13769

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:13769export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/sqlite3 /data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied "update secure set value = 1 where name = 'install_non_market_apps';" > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=60939

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/sqlite3: permission denied

END:60939* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
export PS1=""



# export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.release > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=14443

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

2.3.7

END:14443export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.manufacturer > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=20422

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

Huawei

END:20422export PS1=""



getprop ro.product.model > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=70730

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

U8150

END:70730export PS1=""



getprop ro.build.version.incremental > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=78056

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

eng.aorth.20120306.105455

END:78056export PS1=""



ls -l /system/xbin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=37836

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/xbin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:37836export PS1=""



ls -l /system/bin/su > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=86202

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     ls -l /system/bin/su >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:86202export PS1=""



chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=53011

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/busybox >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:53011export PS1=""



/data/local/tmp/busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=68114

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

/data/local/tmp/busybox: permission denied

END:68114export PS1=""



busybox whoami > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=82093

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     busybox whoami >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:82093export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=45163

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/boomsh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:45163export PS1=""



rm /data/local/tmp/sh > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=26553

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

[1]   Illegal instruction     rm /data/local/tmp/sh >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

END:26553export PS1=""



chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

[1] + Stopped (signal)        chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=62881

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:62881export PS1=""

[1]   Illegal instruction     chmod 700 /data/local/tmp/zergRush >/data/local/tmp/output 2>&1



cd /data/local/tmp/ > /data/local/tmp/output 2>&1

export TEMPRANDOM=37090

export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;cat /data/local/tmp/output

END:37090export PS1=""





export TEMPRANDOM=66693;export PS1=END:$TEMPRANDOM;./zergRush

./zergRush: permission denied

END:66693export PS1=""
```

Comment: Why would you upgrade your busybox? Do you spend so much time in shell?

Comment: @RichardBorcsik I was trying out the [SuperCharger V6 Script from the XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=991276) and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1126940) tutorial said 1.18.3 or newer busybox would cause trouble.. hence I downgraded from my 1.19.x CM7 build. No, I don't spend much time in shell. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should never mess with the system without having a backup.
To get root back you can just re-flash the rom that you're using without wiping anything. This will remove whatever happened with your busybox.

Comment: This is what I am doing right now.. lets see if it solves the problem hopefully.I am not very concerned which is why I don't bother about backups in the first place; here I was just asking if there was some other easier way to solve this problem and perhaps that would give me more insight into the android system.Personally I believe upgrading/downgrading busybox shouldn't cause corruption like I encountered.

Comment: @Power-Inside No it shouldn't cause, but it shouldn't be updated while it's running either. These xda script warriors who instead of bundling their own busybox for their 'fixes' make you modify your system when it's unnecessary cause a lot of bricked phones and trouble.

Comment: I guess this is the best solution.. re installing took a little bit of time which included the time to download the ROM, lol. But it fixed everything neatly quite well.